# How to access the notes field on a GroupPrincipal object

Tags: c#, active-directory

I query all security groups in a specific domain using

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();
```

where ps is a PrincipalSearcher.

I then need to iterate the result (casting it to a GroupPrincipal first ) and locate the ones that contains a specific string in the notes field.

But the Notes field from AD is appearently not a public field in the GroupPrincipal class, doh.
What am I doing wrong ?

Update:
I have given up on this one. It seems like there is no way to access that pesky Notes field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been returning to this challange over and over again, but now I have finally given up. It sure looks like that property is inaccessible.

Answer (score 8):

You can access the 'notes' field of a directory entry as such:

```
// Get the underlying directory entry from the principal
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry UnderlyingDirectoryObject =
     PrincipalInstance.GetUnderlyingObject() as System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry;

// Read the content of the 'notes' property (It's actually called info in the AD schema)
string NotesPropertyContent = UnderlyingDirectoryObject.Properties["info"].Value;

// Set the content of the 'notes' field (It's actually called info in the AD schema)
UnderlyingDirectoryObject.Properties["info"].Value = "Some Text"

// Commit changes to the directory entry
UserDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

Took a little bit of hunting - I had assumed the notes property was indeed called 'notes', ADSIEdit to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

For anybody using the "info" attribute:note that it will throw an exception if using an empty string or null value.

Answer (score 1):

i was able to change that field.

entryToUpdate.Properties["info"].Clear();
entryToUpdate.Properties["info"].Add("some text you want here");

So thanks Brad :)

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation