# Is it possible to get Group Notes from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

Active Directory groups have a 'Notes' property available through the interface (see image below)

[image: AD Group Interface]

Is it possible to retrieve this information in C#?

I can't seem to find the property that holds it. I've tried using the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal` objects but none of them seem to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property called `info` which holds the information shown within this field. But it will only be added to the AD object if a value is available.

If you like to see all elements that have a text within this field. Simply open the AD Browser (`start dsa.msc`) and open a new search. Change the selection within the "Find" combobox to `Custom Search`, click on `Advanced` and enter the text `info=*`. Now you'll get back a list of all elements which having this field.

Comment: That's the one! Microsoft probably thought it was too obvious to call it notes

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but, have you ever checked [`DirectoryEntry.Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.properties.aspx) property?

> Gets the Active Directory Domain Services properties for this
> DirectoryEntry object.

Check out these articles:

- [Accessing Global Address List via System.DirectoryServices Namespace](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/frankalonzo/GlobalAddressList11262005053740AM/GlobalAddressList.aspx?ArticleID=1c1b6bf4-b468-42f6-a40b-b1f1f677dde6)
- [Function to Print DirectoryEntry properties](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2006/04/20/75646.aspx)
- [How to access the notes field on a GroupPrincipal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323817/how-to-access-the-notes-field-on-a-groupprincipal-object/1983762#1983762)