# Using c# System.DirectoryServices to retrieve Group Notes

Tags: c#, directoryservices, active-directory-group

I need to create a procedure to retrieve an AD groups Notes field

[Is it possible to get Group Notes from Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873132/is-it-possible-to-get-group-notes-from-active-directory)

[How to access the notes field on a GroupPrincipal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323817/how-to-access-the-notes-field-on-a-groupprincipal-object)

I have looked that Questions above and they dont seem to answer my question

I only need to read the data in and searched on the group name but then able to access Notes for further work.

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "???", "???", "???");

var insGroupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(context) { Name = "-ppcontrol-*-Global" };

var insPrincipalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher { QueryFilter = insGroupPrincipal };

var results = insPrincipalSearcher.FindAll();

foreach (var p in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

Comment: Can you create a principal object for each result and use principal.GetProperty("Notes"); ? I don't know if notes can be returned like that, but most other fields can.

Comment: Thanks that sorted it